# How do I open an image in the default image viewer using Java on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, image

I have a button to view an image attached to a log entry and when the user clicks that button I want it to open the image in the user's default image viewer on a Windows machine?

How do I know which viewer in the default image viewer?

Right now I'm doing something like this but it doesn't work:

```
String filename = "\""+(String)attachmentsComboBox.getSelectedItem()+"\"";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32.exe C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen "+filename);
```

And by doesn't work I mean it doesn't do anything. I tried to run the command just in the command line and nothing happened. No error, nothing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try with the CMD /C START

```
public class Test2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String fileName = "c:\\temp\\test.bmp";
    String [] commands = {
        "cmd.exe" , "/c", "start" , "\"DummyTitle\"", "\"" + fileName + "\""
    };
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
    p.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Done.");
 }
}
```

This will start the default photo viewer associated with the file extension.

A better way is to use java.awt.Desktop.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;

public class Test2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File f = new File("c:\\temp\\test.bmp");
    Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
    dt.open(f);
    System.out.println("Done.");
 }
}
```

Comment: The first one worked like a charm on XP, but haven't checked it out on Vista or Win7 yet. I might also try the second one. Why would the second one be a better way?

Comment: Because it's using a regular Java SE class (1.6) and it works on others platforms if the file type is supported.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [Desktop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class which does exactly what you need, to open system associated application.

```
File file = new File( fileName );
Desktop.getDesktop().open( file );
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that works well on Windows XP/Vista/7 and can open any type of file (url, doc, xml, image, etc.)

```
Process p;
try {
    String command = "rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler \""+ new File(filename).getAbsolutePath() +"\"";

    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    p.waitFor();

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```